# How does the outermost evaluation strategy evaluate partial application of a function and application of a curried function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, evaluation, currying, partial-application

*Programming in Haskell* by Hutton says

> When   evaluating  an  expression,     in  what    order   should  the     reductions  be  performed?  One     common
>   strategy,   known   as  **innermost evaluation**,   is  to  always  choose  a   redex   that    is  innermost,  in  the sense   that    it
>   contains    no  other   redex.  If  there   is  more    than    one innermost   redex,  by  convention  we  choose  the one that
>   begins  at  the leftmost    position    in  the expression.
>
> Another    common  strategy    for     evaluating  an  expression,     dual    to  innermost   evaluation,     is  to  always
>   choose  a   redex   that    is  outermost,  in  the sense   that    it  is  contained   in  no  other   redex.  If  there   is  more    than
>   one such    redex   then    as  previously  we  choose  that    which   begins  at  the leftmost    position.   Not surprisingly,
>   this    evaluation  strategy    is  known   as  **outermost evaluation**.

In partial application of a function, for example, `mult(3)(4)`, where `mult` is defined as

```
mult    ::  (Int,Int)   ->  Int
mult    (x,y)   =   x   *   y
```

innermost evaluation will first evaluate `mult(3)` as `\y->3*y`, and then evaluate `(\y->3*y)4`. 
How will outermost evaluation evaluate `mult(3)(4)`?

In application of a curried function, for example, `mult'(3)(4)`, where

```
mult'   ::  Int ->  Int ->  Int
mult'   x   =   \y  ->  x   *   y
```

innermost evaluation will first evaluate `mult'(3)` as `\y->3*y`, and then evaluate `(\y->3*y)4`. 
How will outermost evaluation evaluate `mult'(3)(4)`?

Comment: Innermost and outermost evaluation agree on your terms, because they are so simple that they only ever have one redex. But consider `mult (mult 3 4) 5` instead, which now must choose between reducing `mult 3 4` first or reducing `mult (...) 5` first.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks. Is a function application an reduciable expression i.e. redex, if and only if the function application is not the result of another function application, i.e. if and only if the function application must be either a function name or a lambda expression

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027138/is-my-understanding-of-an-reduciable-expression-i-e-redex-correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only sensible way of interpreting:

```
mult :: (Int, Int) -> Int
mult (x,y) = x * y
```

in the context of your larger question is as an *unary* function that takes a single argument of tuple type `(Int, Int)`.  So, `mult` cannot be partially applied.  In particular, `mult(3)` doesn't make any sense, because `3` is not a tuple of type `(Int, Int)`.

As a result, the reduction of the expression `mult (3,4)` in the sense meant by Hutton is the same whether you use outermost or innermost reduction.  There's only one redex/application here, the application of `mult` to `(3,4)`, and both outermost and innermost reduction would give the reductions:

```
mult (3,4)
=>  3 * 4
=>  12
```

For the function:

```
mult' :: Int -> Int -> Int
mult' x y = x * y
```

or equivalently:

```
mult' = \x -> (\y -> x * y)
```

the expression `mult' 3 4` or equivalently `(mult' 3) 4` undergoes innermost reduction as:

```
(mult' 3) 4
= ((\x -> (\y -> x * y)) 3) 4
=> (\y -> 3 * y) 4
=> 3 * 4
=> 12
```

Curiously, outermost reduction proceeds in exactly the same manner:

```
(mult' 3) 4
= ((\x -> (\y -> x * y)) 3) 4     -- (1)
=> (\y -> 3 * y) 4
=> 3 * 4
=> 12
```

That's because the application of `((\x -> \y -> x * y) 3)` to `4` in line (1), while it's the outermost **application**, is not a redex.  It can't be reduced, because the thing being applied `((\x -> \y -> x * y) 3)` isn't a lambda expression.  (It's an application of a lambda expression to an argument.)

Therefore, contrary to first appearances, there's only one redex in line (1), and the innermost and outermost reduction strategies choose the same redex.

Comment: Thanks. Is a function application an reduciable expression i.e. redex, if and only if the function application is not the result of another function application, i.e. if and only if the function application must be either a function name or a lambda expression

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027138/is-my-understanding-of-an-reduciable-expression-i-e-redex-correct

Comment: Another question. "mult(3) doesn't make any sense, because 3 is not a tuple of type (Int, Int)". Isn't `mult(3)` a partial lapplication, so it makes sense?

Comment: Will evaluation of partial applications of a multi-argument function
by using innermost evaluation or outermost evaluation
 be similar to evaluation of  application of a curried function?