# Is my understanding of a reducible expression i.e. redex correct?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, redex

Programming in Haskell by Hutton says:

> An expression that has the form of a function applied to  one or  more arguments that can be ‘reduced’ by performing  the application is called a reducible expression,   or redex for short.

Is a reducible expression i.e. redex exactly

- a function application where the function is not the result of another function application,
- equivalently, a function application where the function is either a function name or a lambda expression?

Is either of the above two points an answer to my previous question at [How does the outermost evaluation strategy evaluate partial application of a function and application of a curried function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023894/how-does-the-outermost-evaluation-strategy-evaluate-partial-application-of-a-fun)?

Comment: Yes. I'd also call `case e of ...` a redex in some cases, when `e` has been evaluated "enough", so that it exposes enough constructors causing the whole expression to be reduced, removing the `case`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What counts as a redex generally depends on the language. The syntax of expressions comes in pairs of introduction and elimination forms of various constructs; a redex is when a particular kind of construct's introduction and elimination forms are juxtaposed appropriately.

For functions, lambdas are introductions (they are the canonical way to create a function when there wasn't one before) and applications are eliminations (they are the canonical way to use a function). So a function redex is the application of a lambda to something, e.g. something of the form `(\x -> e1) e2`. (And only this! The application of a variable to something is *not* a function redex. Normally I would assume this is implied, but your question explicitly asks about this, so...)

For declarations, `let`-bindings or similar are introductions (they are the canonical way to declare that a name has a given value) and variables are eliminations (they are the canonical way to use a declared value). So a declaration redex is a term in the scope of a `let` binding that references a `let`-bound variable, e.g. something of the form `let x = e1 in e2` where `e2` mentions `x`.

For algebraic data types, the type's data constructors are introductions (they are the canonical way to create a value in the type) and `case` expressions are eliminations (they are the canonical way to use a value of algebraic type). So an algebraic data type redex is a `case` whose scrutinee is a fully-saturated constructor application, e.g. `case Constructor arg1 arg2 arg3 ... of pat1 -> e1; pat2 -> e2; ...`.

These are just some examples of pairings. Not all languages have all three of these constructs; and there are languages with additional constructs (e.g. mutable references, exceptions, and the like, each with their own introduction and elimination forms). But I think this should give you a flavor of what is meant by "redex": it is a construction in which some computation can be done to make forward progress in figuring out the value of an expression.

Comment: Thanks. you listed three kinds of redex and I guess  they don't happen to be so. is redex  a concept in some theory? in lambda calculus?

Comment: @Tim Yes, redex is a concept from lambda calculus.

Comment: Does lambda calculus only cover one kind of redex: function redex?

Comment: @Tim There are lambda calculus-based languages with each of the features I mentioned in my answer and more. People talk about "the" lambda calculus, but it isn't like that -- there are many variations on the theme.

Comment: I meant "lambda calculus". A  language which is based on lambda calculus can also be based on something else. Haskell is based on lambda calculus, but also on category theory.

Comment: @Tim This is the only answer I have, and I won't change it, even if you object to it a second time: there are many lambda calculi, no canonical one, and some of them have non-function features and some don't.

Comment: I really don't know much yet, and I really ask questions, not challenge you. Sorry that I gave out a wrong impression.

Answer (score 1):

You also ask ([in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023894/how-does-the-outermost-evaluation-strategy-evaluate-partial-application-of-a-fun#comment100583902_57023997) on the linked entry) *"Isn't mult(3) a partial application, so it makes sense?"*

I thought I've answered this concern [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57020745/849891) to one of your previous questions.

No, the type of `mult` is `(Int, Int) -> Int`, i.e. its argument must have type `(Int, Int)`. But `3` can't have that type; its type is simply `Int`. To calculate the result of `mult 3`, the definition of

```
mult :: (Int, Int) -> Int
mult (x, y) = x * y
```

is consulted, and the calculation proceeds as follows:

```
mult 3
= case 3 of (x, y) -> x * y
***error: pattern match failure
```

Actually, this would be the case if Haskell were an untyped language. Since it's got *types*, the *type mismatch* of `3` and `(Int, Int)` is detected during compilation, and the program is rejected. (*)

---

<sub>(*) `3 :: Num a => a`, i.e. its type can be `Int`, `Float`, etc., but certainly it can't be a tuple ... well, without having a `Num` instance defined for tuples it can't, but let's say there isn't one. This also means the program will actually be rejected at *run* time after having found no *Num* instances were defined for any tuple types in any of the imported modules... but let's leave it as a footnote.</sub>

Comment: Do you mean Haskell doesn't allow partial application?

Comment: of what? if `mult (x,y) = x*y`, then `mult 3` is ill-typed. It has no meaning; is rejected by the type system. If `prod x y = x*y`, then `prod :: Int -> Int -> Int` and for `x :: Int`, `prod x :: Int -> Int` is well typed, has meaning, is allowed.

Comment: Is partial application defined in Haskell?

Comment: not per se, no. what is defined is simply *application*: for `f :: a -> b` and `x :: t`, `f x :: b` provided `a ~ t` (i.e. under the unification of `a` and `t`). so for `g :: a -> c -> d` and `x :: t`, `g x :: c -> d`, under `a ~ t` -- this is because it is *actually* `g :: a -> (c -> d)`! (and the `b` in `f`'s type could just as well have been `c -> d`, too).

Comment: this is so complicated in other languages that it trips you up, makes you expect some complex stuff is going on here in Haskell as well. But it is actually extremely simple and uncomplicated in Haskell. You just need to stop thinking in terms of "implementations" and switch to thinking in terms of "definitions". `f x y = ...` and `f x = (\ y -> ...)` are just two different ways to write down the one same thing.

Comment: Is arithmetic addition operator `+`'s type `num a, b,c => a -> b -> c` or `num a, b,c => (a,b) -> c`?

Comment: @Tim Neither. Haskell's `(+)` has type `Num a => a -> a -> a`.

Comment: @DanielWagner why reusing `a` in three roles, when the three can take different values?

Comment: @Tim Because all three values must have the same type. It does not make sense to add a complex number to a cyclotomic number, or a polynomial to a rational. Adding two different values that are both rational makes perfectly good sense, though (and the result of the addition is again a rational).

Comment: @DanielWagner I realize `a` represent a type not a value

Comment: @WillNess Thanks. I see. "this would be the case if Haskell were an untyped language" and "this is so complicated in other languages that it trips you up". What "other languages" do you have in mind?

Comment: the languages with `f(x,y)` function call syntax, like e.g. C, where they must have a special construct to enable partial application.